# Trying to read source docx files and transcribe these to target .docx files. What is not working is the header/footer parts

Tags: python, python-docx

The header, in this case, contains a table with a cell containing a company Logo and a few other cells with alphanumeric ID's. The footer has pagination and a time stamp.

I've looked at using template (docxtpl) and the python-docx 0.8.10 but for header/footers with graphic stuff or tables there doesn't seem to be a solution. I'm not sure yet how to use templates! The docx module doesn't specify how to use non-text in headers.

This project, my first with .docx files, requires that I read thousands of Word documents and transcribe them to similar modified files. Everything works except this final step with the Headers/Footers.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? _but header/footers with graphic stuff or tables doesn’t seem provide the solution._ Can you expand on that?

Comment: Invisible Headers/Footers resolved!